# MySQL Performance: 2 Tables or 1 Table with a LONGTEXT type

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store data in a table that looks like this:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
        id int unsigned not null auto_increment,
        type varchar(15) default '' not null,
        name varchar(40) default '' not null,
        folder varchar(25) default '' not null,
        data mediumtext default '' not null,
        shared_network bool,
        owner int unsigned,
        shared_label bool,
        creator int unsigned,
        thumbnail int unsigned,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )$charset_collate;";
```

My first question is, because the `Data` value is going to be a large value, would it be more performant to separate this into two tables: 1 with `ID` and `Data` and 1 with everything else?

Second, if it IS more performant to use two tables, which of these would be more performant: Running two queries, one to find the `ID`s that I need and one to get the `Data` value for those `ID`s. Or, an outer join on the `ID` (I would need all the values).

Finally, if an outer join is the best way to go, is `ID` a `FOREIGN KEY` on the table with `ID` and `Data` or is it a foreign key on the table with everything else?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

An example query would be:

```
SELECT * from $table_name WHERE
type='something'
AND shared_network=TRUE
AND shared_label=TRUE
```

Comment: Without a query, it is really hard to give any sensible advice on performance.

Comment: this may be appropriate: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-blob.html

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've updated the question with an example query.

Comment: @pala_ Thanks for that link - that seems to suggest that I should separate them into 2 tables.

Comment: this could also be a case of premature optimisation.  if you are always fetching the `data` field in every query, may as well be one table. but your best bet is simply to profile your options and see which performs best for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT *
from $table_name
WHERE type ='something' AND shared_network = TRUE AND shared_label = TRUE;
```

You can create an index on `table(type, shared_network, shared_label)`.  The index will satisfy the `where` clause.  The rest of the work is fetching the appropriate rows.  There is no advantage to having two tables.